# GPAY Direct tokenization

Tags: google-pay

I am trying to implement GPAY to my desktop application, where users can pay through website and also get paid.

I am trying o use GPAY direct tokenization method with out using 3rd party gateway. I got the encryption part.
1) In case of direct tokenization,Do my application need to act as a payment processor and have code which handles charging different cards. IF so,how complicated is this and I am looking for any reference material.

2) how complex is to get PCI DSS compliance

3) Overall how much time it takes to implement GPAy with out 3rd part payment gateway?

Comment: I haven't personally gone through PCI DSS compliance myself, but I imagine it is quite involved and includes independent auditors. Unless you've got a good reason not to, the recommendation is to use a PSP. FYI, refer to one of my previous answers for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57390443/google-pay-payment-integration-with-using-direct-tokenization/58863800#58863800